# Webservice request from SoapUI not returning results

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, workbench

I am working on an assignment where I need to setup a webservice in Salesforce. The other system will have a search screen on their side and they should be able to search Salesforce for list of accounts given a partial account name. As a POC, I developed a simple REST webservice. The code is below.

```
/*******************************************************************************

    Description - Sample Apex REST service with GET and POST methods

    Service EndPoint : https://test.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/accounts/

    {
    "accountName" : "TEST",

    "accountPhone" : "",

    "accountWebsite" : "http://www.abc.com/"
    }

    *******************************************************************************/

    @RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/accounts/*')
    global with sharing class REST_AccountService {


    @HttpPost

    global static AccountWrapper doPost(String accountName, String accountPhone, String accountWebsite) {

    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

    AccountWrapper response = new AccountWrapper();

    System.debug('Request = ' + req.requestBody);
    String acctName = '%' + accountName + '%';
    String acctPhone = accountPhone;
    String acctWebsite = accountWebsite;
    System.debug('Request parameters = ' + acctName + ' \t ' + acctPhone + ' \t ' + acctWebsite);

    List<Account> accLst = new List<Account>();
    //Account acc = null;
    try {
        accLst = [Select Id, Name from Account where Name LIKE :acctName];
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Hit Exception. ' + ex);
    }

    System.debug(accLst);

    for (Account acc : accLst) {
        response.acctList.add(acc);
        response.status = 'Success';
        response.message = 'Your Accounts ware fetched successfully.';
    }
    System.debug('Response = ' + response);
    return response;
}

global class AccountWrapper {
    public List<Account> acctList;
    public String status;
    public String message;

    public AccountWrapper(){
        acctList = new List<Account>();
    }
}
```

}

The above service is working fine from workbench when  I call with EndPoint URL /services/apexrest/v1/accounts and with the request message.

```
{
"accountName" : "Test",
"accountPhone" : "",
"accountWebsite" : "http://cumobileapps.com/"
}
```

However, when I call the same service with the same request message from SoapUI, I am getting a null response as shown below.

```
{
   "status": null,
   "message": null,
   "acctList": []
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the response from Salesforce workbench.

[image]

I am stumbled as to why this is happening. Has anyone faced this issue before? Any help is appreciated.

Debug logs when calling from soap ui is below.

[image]

Debug logs when calling from workbench is below.
[image]

Comment: What do your debug statements show? That looks like it would be the expected outcome if no Accounts are returned by the query.

Comment: It sounds like your payload is incorrectly configured and all the values are null. Check the method, Content-Type, Accept headers.

Comment: I have edited my original comment to include the debug logs. As you can see from the screenshot, the request params are there, but the SOQL doesn't seem to be returning any values when the service is called via SoapUI.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli Are you authenticating as the same user in both situations?

Comment: No. For workbench, I am running as myself (System Administrator profile) and for SoapUI, I am using a service account which has access to Accounts and Contacts object. It is a API Only user account with limited access in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a record-level visibility issue.

Your web service class is running `with sharing`, which is good. The authenticated context user's record-level visibility will be applied to query results.

Your class creates a new `AccountWrapper` regardless of the results it finds:

```
AccountWrapper response = new AccountWrapper();
```

But it only populates any of its elements if at least one Account is found:

```
for (Account acc : accLst) {
    response.acctList.add(acc);
    response.status = 'Success';
    response.message = 'Your Accounts ware fetched successfully.';
}
```

The response you are receiving

```
{
   "status": null,
   "message": null,
   "acctList": []
}
```

is consistent with your code returning a *newly-initialized, empty `AccountWrapper`* - which is exactly what we should expect it to do if `accLst` is empty. Since you note that for SoapUI you are using

> service account which has access to Accounts and Contacts object. It is a API Only user account with limited access in Salesforce

I am confident that that's our culprit: the SoapUI user does not have record-level visibility to the test Accounts you are using.

Easy fix to prove this is true: give that user the View All permission on Account and see what happens.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your help. The API User profile had the "View All" permission on the Accounts checked. However, it appears that some other developer has changed the profile of the service account from 'API User' to 'Basic API User' for which the permissions are not given (Multiple developers are working on the same project).  Once I switched the profile of the service account to 'API User', it is working fine.